# where to put 'view results tree' to see results of jmeter 'debug sampler'

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to use the 'debug sampler'(DS) in JMeter as I need to check that a 'regular expression extractor'(REE) is picking up an authentication token OK, but I can't work out how to get JMeter to show me what it's picking up.  I don't have enough reputation points to post a screenshot of the tree inside JMeter, so I'll try to describe it(!)

Under the thread group I have 3 children, (1) the HTTP request which has a get for the page I'm after and the REE in it, (2) the DS, and (3) a 'view results tree' (VRT) listener in which I'm hoping to see the results from the DS.

I can't put the DS under the REE in (1)(it won't move there) and the VRT just below the DS doesn't show any JMeter variables, only the same output as a VRT within the HTTP request group (1).

Any suggestions where i could put things or how to configure them to see what the REE is picking up?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have used the Debug sampler as below

```
Test Plan
--Thread Group
----Some HTTP Request
------Regular Expression Extractor
----Debug Sampler
----View Result Tree
```

In that case it should work. But if your VRT was under HTTP request and DS under the TG then it wont work. Also make sure in DS 'JMeter variables' is set to true.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it is, and I have the JMeter variables set to true, but for some reason I'm not seeing anything with my variable names (as detailed in the REE).  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is Debug Sampler appearing in your VRT?

Comment: Also for example if you have set REE variable name as fetchVal then it will appear in Response data tab of Debug sampler in VST as fetchVal=Sample Test
fetchVal_g=1
fetchVal_g0=is a "Sample Test".
fetchVal_g1=Sample Test

Comment: No, I can't see DS in my VRT at all.  Debug Sampler doesn't have a response tab, only 3 drop down boxes with booleans (JMeter properties, JMeter Variables, System Properties).  Neither Debug Sampler nor any thing I rename it to appears in the VRT.  the Response data tab of the VRT shows the html of the webpage the REE should be extracting from - the VRTs basically acting like it doesn't know there's a REE anywhere at all.

Comment: You are right, DS attached to the test plan will only have three drop downs. For DS not appearing in the VRT - either your DS is disabled or does not fall in the scope of VRT. So make sure that DS is enabled and also attach the VRT to the Test plan itself so DS will fall into its scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it as Child of Test Plan you will see all Sampler so you will see Debug Sampler.
If you put it as a child of Debug Sampler you will only see results of this Debug Sampler.

To see variables,in View Results Tree, click on Sampler and select Response Data Tab.

Comment: should 'sampler' be an entry in the long left hand pane of 'view results'? if it is, then in that pane I only have the HTTP Request under thread group, and then two entries under that: one for the webpage I've asked it to get (which has a redirection message); and one for the page it's redirected to. should there be an entry there for the DS?